# Dudas prototype JS

Tags: javascript

Hola lo que estoy a punto de preguntar quisas suene un poco estúpido pero no encuentro una respuesta concreta:

Cuando creo esto, tengo dudas:

```
const Padre = function(name){ this.name = name; };

Padre.prototype.fn = function(){return this.name};
```

Cual es la diferencia entre:

------------ 1 --------------------

```
const clon = Padre.bind(this);

const hijo = new clon('Luis');

hijo.fn();
```

------------ 2 --------------------

```
const clon2 = Object.create(Padre.prototype);

const hijo2 = new clon2.constructor('Luis');

hijo2.fn();
```

------------ 3 --------------------

```
const clon3 = new Object(Padre)

const hijo3 = new clon3('Luis');

hijo3.fn();
```